# Is it possible to aggregate data from contacts to accounts?

Tags: contact, account

Is it possible that when looking on the account tab, I will see it's contacts related lists of: Email Status, Activity History, etc?

The idea is that each contact has its own list of actions, but when looking at the account, that list can be empty, and thus misleading, and can also create duplicates and excessive work.

I want that if a contact has a piece of information, I will have the ability to see it as a whole master list from the accounts page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All standard activities do roll up from the Contact to the Account.

For custom objects you can create a hidden Account look up on the custom object and workflow the account the contact is associated to.  This will create the related list on the Account and you will be able to see all of the contact related list information.

Comment: Thanks, this is true. But I don't want to create another hidden field. But thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Visualforce page embedded in your Account page layout, with a custom Apex controller extension, to simulate a related list that includes all Activities from all of the Contacts on the Account. Likewise for just about any related list on the Contact page. I think Email Status might be hard to query for, but most other objects are available in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't code or have access to developers, you can also try dynamic report links on the Account page. The basic idea that that you're looking at the Acme account page, and you can click a link that opens a reports that's dynamically prefiltered to show data related to Acme. Move to the Smith Inc. page? The linked report shows Smith Inc. data.

You should be able to build a report that shows email statuses related to contacts related to Account X--the link automatically fills in Account X based on which account you're looking at.

Building the link is pretty straightforward. There are a number of explanations on how to do this all over the web (some good, some bad, some dated). Here are a couple of the better ones.

http://www.luneos.com/blog/salesforce-instant-reports/

https://ssl.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_web_integration_links.pdf

Instructions vary slightly depending on if you want to pull up the report via a HYPERLINK() in a formula, a Custom Link or a button.

Beware: this opens the door to all kinds of seemingly magical things you can do with hacking Salesforce URL's via buttons and links.